# build rpm spec file to carry one file and execute one command

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

im trying to build rpm file which include

```
1 file /usr/local/stats.sh
```

the rpm will do one thing

```
echo -e "*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/sh  /usr/local/stats.sh"  >> /var/spool/cron/root
```

i already start with

```
Name:           stats
Version:        0.1
Release:        el%{redhat_releasever}%{redhat_releasever_minor}.1
Summary:        stats
Source0:        %{svn_url_Systems}/%{name}.spec
BuildArch:      noarch
Group:          %{repo_name_Systems}
License:        stat
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)


%description
Script 


%prep

%setup -cT


%build

%{__mkdir} -p %{buildroot}/%{_sysconfdir}/

echo -e "*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/sh /usr/local/stats.sh "  >> /var/spool/cron/root

%changelog
```

any tips to make it this rpm spec file correct and working !

Answer (score 8):

it's easier to not manipulate the crontab in '/var/spool/cron/root'. Use the /etc/cron.d directory instead. Create a single file containing your crontab-line. Install this file in this directory.
The advantage is that this file will be automatically uninstalled when you uninstall the rpm-package.

So, all you need is to build a rpm file that will install two files.

The %build macro is not the thing you need. you need to arrange the packaging according the target directories on the host.

```
%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/usr/local
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/etc/cron.d

cp ...mysource/stats.sh              %{buildroot}/usr/local
cp ...mysource/mystatstiming.cron    %{buildroot}/etc/cron.d
```

then you need to define the file flag settings:

```
%files
%defattr(755,root,root)
/usr/local/stat.sh

%defattr(644,root,root)
/etc/cron.d/mystatstiming.cron
```